# Unity Why wont my FPS pause menu stop the camera rotation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on the pause menu for my FPS game and so far I am able to get the pause menu panel to show up and interact with it, but it does not stop the camera movement. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
public class PauseMenuu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static bool GameIsPaused = false;
    public GameObject PauseMenu;

    private void Start()
    {

    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            if (GameIsPaused)
            {
                Resume();
            }
            else
            {
                Pause();
            }
        }
    }

    void Resume()
    {
        PauseMenu.SetActive(false);
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
        GameIsPaused = false;
    }

    void Pause()
    {
        PauseMenu.SetActive(true);
        Time.timeScale = 0f;
        GameIsPaused = true;
    }
}
```

here is my camera rotate code if this helps you figure out what is going on with the camera.

```
public class CameraRotate : MonoBehaviour
{
public float speed;
float time = 14.0f;
public GameObject HeadCamera;
public bool updateOn = true;

void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(updateOff());
}

void Update()
{
    Rotation();
}
void Rotation()
{
    RotateX += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * RotationSpeed;
    RotateY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * RotationSpeed;
    RotateY = Mathf.Clamp(RotateY, MinYAxis, MaxYAxis);
    Camera.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(-RotateY, 0f, 0f);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, RotateX, 0f);
}
}
```

Comment: I don't know ... where is the code for the implementation of the Camera movement/rotation?

Comment: It sounds like your camera movement isn't tied to the Time construct within Unity. Is camera movement determined purely by input or variables incrementing arbitrarily every frame? Make sure all the movement scripts around your camera refer to Time.deltaTime or some part of the calculation connected to the Time system so the `Time.timescale = 0f` actually affects it.

Comment: Wild guess since the camera code isn't present, but setting the timescale to 0 doesn't necessarily freeze your camera. Sort of like a scene from The Matrix, where the action is stopped but the camera can still move around.

Comment: @GraphTheory thats what I was thinking after doing more research, but I still have not found a way to fix it.

Comment: @EthanK-B Adding your camera code can help us answer your question and also help people in the future who have the same question.

Comment: @GraphTheory I added it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could solve it for you, try rotating the camera relative to its own position. So what you would do is add this to the top of your function call:

```
void Rotation()
{
    if(Time.deltaTime == 0){
        return;
    }
...
```

Also note that you might need to change a couple of values to get the rotation amount like before.

Hope it helps!

Comment: So Sorry but I put the wrong camera code (thats what happens when you have been up for 2 nights straight). I updated the post with the correct code.

Comment: Ok now it makes more sense. I edited the answer and it should work now.

Comment: It does work, but it makes the camera glitchy and it does move well.

Comment: Okay I would guess that is because Time.DeltaTime is being variable throught. Restore the code to the previous one and check my edit above.

Comment: Works flawlessly. Thank you.